# mysql 3 different sort in 1time

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Here is my table:

```
 id | is_quick_plus | is_quick |   top_date |       date
----|---------------|----------|------------|------------
  1 |             1 |        0 | 2017-11-29 | 2017-11-01
  2 |             0 |        1 |       NULL | 2017-11-01
  3 |             1 |        0 |       NULL | 2017-11-02
  4 |             0 |        1 | 2017-11-28 | 2017-11-01
  5 |             0 |        0 |       NULL | 2017-11-03
```

The current sort is (1,4,2,3,5)

1 and 4 have top_date other sort by date

when I sort by

```
is_quick_plus DESC, is_quick DESC, top_date DESC, date DESC
```

one row has no top_date going up because it has is_quick_plus but has expired .. and should sort by date ..

I just to first sort by is_quick_plus and top_date, then is_quick and top_date, then by date ... in 1 query

Comment: you should use DESC and not DESE

Comment: it's was typing mistake here please read cheerfully my problem , thank you I edited it , let me howcan I do it ?

Comment: Please add an example of the table's current data, current output and desired output. Thanks.

Comment: edded , check it out

Comment: @OfirBaruch please let me know that's possible or not ?

Comment: Please read your own question before publishing it. It has so many typos, I can hardly understand what you want to ask.

Comment: Can you give us the order you would want the example output to be? If you order by what you say you do `is_quick_plus DESC, is_quick DESC, top_date DESC, date DESC`, the order that you get is 1, 3, 4, 2, 5. What would you want it to be instead?

Comment: I want to get 1,4,2,3,5 first

Comment: first sort by is_quick_plus and top_date and then sort by is_quick and   top_date

Comment: If you expect 1,4,2,3,5 order means, you can simply execute as:  select * from t1 order by top_date DESC ,date ASC;

Comment: Dear sir please let me know to set order by is_quick_plus DESC, is_quick DESC, top_date DESC, date DESC . it's not work

Comment: your question is not clear to me  .. you should add  the query you are using, the actual result and the expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a group BY in the ending of the select